# How to load and execute a Java file when booting on Linux?

Tags: linux, java, raspberry-pi

I recently started programming my very first java project. An automatic alarm clock.

I did all the work and have now my compiled `.class` file. But to get it working, I need it to start everytime I restart my machine. So all I want to know is how to get Linux to start a Java class file every restart.

Comment: Any particular distro?

Comment: I use a raspberry pi. OS is raspbian I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference your executable in `/etc/rc.local` file (or add a system startup service `/etc/rc2.d`: the Pi boots to runlevel 2).

There, you put a normal `java` invocation with full path (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/java ...` or `/usr/bin/java ...`).

If you want the output to be logged to a file, you either leverage `syslog` function or redirect the output to a logfile (or two separate logfiles, one for stdout log, one for error log), i.e.

```
/path/to/java -JAVA_OPTIONS your.class >> /var/log/logfile.log 2>> /var/log/logfile.err
```

The first time, run the command from the command line to verify it is properly working.

Comment: Where do I have to put my Main.class file? When it's in the ~ folder its not found.

Comment: @xMaschx You can put it anywhere. You just need to type the path to it, if it's in ~ then use /path/to/java -JAVA_ARGS /home/YOURUSER/your.class

Comment: Already tried it, but when I execute the command "/usr/bin/java -classpath javampd.jar:. /home/pi/Testing" it says "mainclass .home.pi.Testing could not be found.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_of_a_Jar_file

Comment: Didn't help me :( I only have an *.class file and no project / package . Btw im totally a noob in linux and java :)

Comment: You said you had a .JAR file? If so, you can run it directly. Say instead that you have a /usr/local/bin/yourfile.jar file, in which (check with `unzip -l jarfile) your class is `com.xmaschx.alarum`; then you would run it as `/path/to/java -classpath /usr/local/bin/yourfile.jar com.xmasch.alarum`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I created a *.jar file and wrote the java command in /etc/rc.local! now it works!